# C++, Winsocket DLL Send injection

Tags: c++, winsock, send, code-injection

Thanks for reading. I've been trying to send packets with "send" from Winsock from an injected DLL, but i coulnd't do it, i've seen alot of guides about HOOKING "recv" and "send", but not about sending packets by using "send" or "WSASend" and the same socket, is there a way to use "send" and use the same socket?, should i get the socket handle?. Thanks

Comment: "but i couldn't do it" - Can you be more specific? What happened exactly?

Comment: I had an ASM hook to "send", and then i tried to change the output by moving the buffer to a variable and then returning the altered buffer to the original "send" function, thats how i tried to make it, but its not what i really need to know, i dont need a hook to "send" i need to know how to make a "send" with the same socket as the created by the application. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

> should i get the socket handle?

Yes if you can get the socket handle, I don't see what the problem could be: because your injected DLL is running inside the same process, it is allowed to use the existing handle (if you can discover the handle value, perhaps by hooking one of the socket functions to see what socket handle the hooked application is using).

You probably can't reopen the same socket to get a new handle of your own.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons. Some of them I might think of:

1. You are trying to send to the socket that has already been closed. If you are doing you send() calls asynchronously to the main application activity, the application might have already closed the socket by the time you are trying to send. Try to send within the hook function for send() or recv() calls on the socket that you are using to send your data.
2. There is another send() call on the same socket in another thread.
3. The buffer length parameter is not aligned with the real buffer length (might occur if you just change the buffer parameter, but leave the length parameter intact from the original call)

Hope this helps.